# Long text strings in source file, result in multi-lines in output file

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I need to run a XSLT-produced output file (XHTML) in a technical testbench.

Each time I use a long text string (from source file) and perform a XSLT, the testbench does not approve the document. It seems th reason is that the output file (XHTML) is taking the long text  string and split it into several lines.

In "xsl:output" I have set the attribute "suppress-indentation", but it looks that attribute only controls the indentation of the node elements (tags), not the node values length.

In my environment I have also controlled the output file in a terminal to secure that the problem is not only isolated to my programming text editor.

Is there a way of controlling the length of when XSLT would judge to cut a long string into several lines?

My environment:

- Saxon-HE 10.5J from Saxonica
- Java version 11.0.11

You can see the behavior in the xsltfiddle:
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxWZS72/4

**Data:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
    <content-cut>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</content-cut>
    <content-no-cut>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</content-no-cut>
</data>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="3.0"
>

  <xsl:output method="xhtml" indent="yes" suppress-indentation="content" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>MyTitle</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          
        <string-one>
            <xsl:value-of select="content-cut"/>
        </string-one>
        
        <string-two>
            <xsl:value-of select="content-no-cut"/>
        </string-two>  

      </body>
    </html>
    
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html><html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/><title>MyTitle</title></head>
   <body>
      <string-one>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
         ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
         ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </string-one>
      <string-two>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</string-two>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Wanted result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html><html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/><title>MyTitle</title></head>
   <body>
      <string-one>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </string-one>
      <string-two>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</string-two>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Saxon is known to insert line breaks in paragraphs for readability if you use indententation, I think the commercial editions have a proprietary output property to turn that theoretically by setting a very high line length as the default. I don't remember whether there is an easy solution for HE; and relying on indentation on the one hand while wanting certain formatting preserved on the other hand is a difficult approach.

Comment: https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/extensions/output-extras/serialization-parameters.html has `saxon:line-length` with a default of `80` and "With the HTML output method, text lines are split at this line length when possible. ".

Comment: The spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-31/#HTML_INDENT suggests that, for example, for `pre` element no whitespace should be added inside the content and I think Saxon honours that so perhaps, as `string-one` or `string-two` is not any HTML element anyway, use `pre` instead. I think that technically, `suppress-indentation="string-one string-two"` should also work but let's see what Michael Kay says.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your "testbench" is relying on behaviour that is not required by the XSLT specification, and is probably not required by the real application. In such situations, the best approach is generally to relax the requirements of the test bench, so that it doesn't impose unreasonable requirements on the transformation output.

Testing serialized XML output is always tricky anyway, especially when `indent="yes"` has been set, which makes many aspects of the output implementation-defined.

You're using `suppress-indentation="content"`, but you don't have an element called `content` in the serialized output. Have you tried `suppress-indentation="string-one string-two"? I think that ought to work according to the spec; if not, we should probably fix it.

But I think you should probably be reviewing how you do your testing. Comparing serialized indented output is just too fragile for comfort.

Comment: I updated the question by updating the xsltfiddle with proper value in "suppress-indentation". That specific change did not improve the result. I agree that combining indent="yes" with the need of avoiding cutting long strings in element values is asking for errors and instability. - However, in this particular case the testbench is not in my reach of premises, thus I cannot "relax" it.It would be useful for test variations being able to control and adjust the maximum accepted text width for element values, though.

Comment: Feels a bit akward that I am able to auto-produce approx. 10.000 lines of XHTML and the only current outstanding issue that prevents from performing this transformation 100% automatic, is the split of lines. Note that I highly appreciate your time in providing answers and comments.

Comment: I should have added a link to a Saxon issue raised on this: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5018

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the test case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:param name="suppress-indentation-in" as="xs:string*" static="yes" select="'p', 'string-data'"/>
  
  <xsl:param name="test-elements" as="xs:string*" static="yes" select="'div', $suppress-indentation-in, 'pre', 'span',"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5.0" _suppress-indentation="{$suppress-indentation-in}"/>
  
  <xsl:mode on-multiple-match="use-last"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>suppress-indenation test in {$suppress-indentation-in}</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1 data-suppress-indentation-in="{$suppress-indentation-in}">suppress-indentation test in {$suppress-indentation-in}</h1>
        <xsl:iterate select="$test-elements">
          <xsl:param name="root" select="*"/>
          <section>
            <h2>{.}</h2>
            <xsl:element name="{.}">{$root}</xsl:element>
          </section>
        </xsl:iterate>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:next-match/>
    <xsl:comment xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/">Run with {system-property('xsl:product-name')} {system-property('xsl:product-version')} {system-property('Q{http://saxon.sf.net/}platform')}</xsl:comment>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to run it against the input taken from your sample

```
<text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</text>
```

and even with Saxon 10.5 the result shows the `suppress-indentation` is not taken into account as the output is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>suppress-indenation test in p string-data</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1 data-suppress-indentation-in="p string-data">suppress-indentation test in p string-data</h1>
      <section>
         <h2>div</h2>
         <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
            ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </section>
      <section>
         <h2>p</h2>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
            ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </section>
      <section>
         <h2>string-data</h2>
         <string-data>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
            ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</string-data>
      </section>
      <section>
         <h2>pre</h2>
         <pre>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</pre>
      </section>
      <section>
         <h2>span</h2><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
            ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span></section>
   </body>
</html><!--Run with SAXON HE 10.5.1 -->
```

As https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-31/#HTML_INDENT says:

> Whitespace characters MUST NOT be added in the content of an element
> whose expanded QName matches a member of the list of expanded QNames
> in the value of the suppress-indentation parameter

I think Saxon until 10.5 has a bug here: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5018.

The only workaround seems to use the `pre` element.

Bug https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5018 has, however, been fixed and the latest release 10.6 now supports `suppress-indentation` just fine.

Comment: I tested pre-tags wrapping. It works in xsltfiddle and produced output file (XHTML) in my environment. Controlling the output file in a web browser results though that the test string is twice a wide as the document. This is probably normal due to using pre-tags but width of text string is not align with rest of document. Without a pre-tag the internet browser can receive a very long text string in XHTML and figure out how to present the document with proper width line cut. So pre-tag is not working as workaround. As temporary solution I set supress-indent to "no".

Comment: @Toolbox, well, I suggested the `pre` element only as you seemed to look at the Saxon output and only for `pre` Saxon doesn't seem to enforce the line breaking with HE. If rendering in the browser is also a target, I would suggest a second transformation step. Otherwise you need to use CSS to have the `pre` content look "normal": `<pre style="white-space: pre-wrap; font-style: normal; font-family: serif;">`.

Comment: Yes, I missed to explain that the end result target is a document that user can see in a internet browser.